# Ansible 2.5 Include Roles with Variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

```
ansible 2.5.5
...
 python version = 3.6.5 (default, Jun 17 2018, 12:26:58) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)]
```

I'm trying to loop over a role and apply dynamic variable.

It seems like the variables never get applied  which means the CLI variables doesn't get overwritten like I'd hope it would ...

could this be a variable precedence thing?

I am declaring the variables `service_name` and `version` in the CLI as well in an attempt to deploy one service and multiple dependent services.

```
tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: "check_deps"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ deps_info_list }}"

    - include_role:
        name: "ecs_service"
      vars:
        service_name: "{{depsvcitem.name}}"
        version: "{{depsvcitem.version}}"
      loop: "{{deps_info_list}}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: depsvcitem
```

When I call it with ...

```
# args.yml
cluster: "devops-poc"
service_name: "bss-com-api-feed-validation"
version: "1.0.0.8"
```

and ...

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/myplaybook.yml -e @args.yml
```

The variables to the called roles in the above loop gets 
 overwritten  with the values from `args.yml` instead of the dynamic variables in the loop overriding the values of `args.yml`

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting applied"? Can you please make a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indeed a variable precedence issue, since the variables defined on the CLI with `-e` take precedence.

The way I solved it was to change the variable names defined on the CLI:

```
from service_name to orig_service_name
from version to orig_version
```

Then in the playbook assign and unassign the role variables as needed like so ...

```
tasks:
# first we set the variables that the roles are looking for ...
- set_fact:
    service_name: "{{ orig_service_name }}"
    version: "{{ orig_version }}"

# Then we call the role that checks dependencies
- include_role:
    name: "check_deps"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ deps_info_list }}"

# If we have dependencies
# and those dependencies are not running
# we create them in the below block
- block:
  # First make sure the the below variables are unset
  # so as to avoid variable precedence overwrites
  - set_fact:
      service_name: false
      version: false

  # For each non-existing or non-running service
  # we run the `ecs_service` role
  - include_role:
      name: "ecs_service"
    vars:
      service_name: "{{depsvcitem.name}}"
      version: "{{depsvcitem.version}}"
    loop: "{{deps_info_list}}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: depsvcitem

  # Set the variables to what the `ecs_service` role needs
  # in preparation for creating the parent service
  - set_fact:
      service_name: "{{ orig_service_name }}"
      version: "{{ orig_version }}"

  when: deps_info_list|length|int > 0

# Create the parent or only service
- include_role:
    name: "ecs_service"
```